# Unable to implement textwatcher correctly in android

Tags: android

I was looking for a way to find out what the user was typing in an `EditText` and I stumbled upon the `TextWatcher`. Problem is I don't understand what the parameters refer to in the function. I want to keep track of the text being entered by the user letter by letter. I can't figure out which argument is the correct subscript no. I have tried different variations but haven't had any luck with those.

**Essentially I want to save text entered in an array until the user presses the ','button or exceeds the limit of 24 characters.**
Please advise.

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    // inputans.setOnKeyListener(this);

    Button go;
    TextView answer;
    TextView check;
    EditText inputans, inputq;
    boolean done1 = false;
    char[] ans = new char[30];
    String predef = "Please answer my question";
    char[] predefc = predef.toCharArray();
    int len = predefc.length;
    int i = 0;
    char[] substring = new char[30];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialisevars();
        go.setEnabled(false);
        go.setOnClickListener(this);

        inputans.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                if ((count - before) > 0) {
                    char current = s.charAt(before);                   
                    if (current == '.' || i >= 24) { // 24 check
                        // ans[i]='\0';
                        // inputans.setText(predef,
                        // TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                        check.setText(predef);
                        go.setEnabled(true);
                    } else {

                        ans[i] = current;
                        i++; // char[] substring = char[30]; back button
                                // problem,check if prev length - current length
                                // >0

                        int m;
                        for (m = 0; m <= i; m++) {
                            substring[m] = predefc[m];
                        }

                        check.setText(substring.toString());
                        // substring[m]='\0';
                        /*
                         * inputans.setText(substring.toString(),
                         * TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                         */

                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }

    private void initialisevars() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGo);
        answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAns);
        inputans = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTricky);
        inputq = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etQues);
        check = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bGo: {

            answer.setText(ans.toString()); 

        }
            break;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can pls give some more details of what you want and what is not working in your code?

Comment: Essentially I want to save text entered in an array until the user presses the ','button or exceeds the limit of 24 characters.

Comment: Edit you question and post the same. It is unclear for people who visit the post.

Comment: Also am I correct in assuming that char sequences can be manipulated just like arrays?

Comment: @user2301560 `String` implements `Charsequence`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android documentation, you can read that:

> public abstract void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int
>   before, int count) Added in API level 1
>
> This method is called to notify you that, within `s`, the `count`
>   characters beginning at `start` have just replaced old text that had
>   length `before`. It is an error to attempt to make changes to s from
>   this callback.

It means, that:

- `s` is already a modified text (you can get it's length, by
  `s.length()`)
- `count` is number of characters that have been added
- `start` is position in which new characters have been added
- `before` is length of text before changes

Basically to achieve what you want, I'd rather go with this approach instead of arrays:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialisevars();
    go.setEnabled(false);
    go.setOnClickListener(this);

    inputans.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            if ((s.length() - before) > 0) {  // Check if text is longer than before changing
                char current = s.charAt(before);                   
                if (current == '.' || s.length() >= 24) {
                    check.setText(predef);
                    go.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    check.setText(s);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

Simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

[`beforeTextChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#beforeTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) is called before any change happens, here you can get the old contents, which are just going to change:

```
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

  String toBeChanged = s.subSequence(start,start+count).toString();

}
```

---

To get what replaced the previous contents, use [`onTextChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), this is called just as the replacement is done:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

  String replacement = s.subSequence(start,start+count).toString();

}
```

---

If you are not interested in *what* is being changed and just want to know *something changed*, just for the purpose of to save it, or compare it, or validate it etc etc, you can use the third method [`afterTextChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged%28android.text.Editable%29). This method is to be used when you don't want to interfere with user editing one or more characters:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  String newString = s.toString(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks but these are strings right. How do I get the latest char entered by the user?

Comment: @user2301560 User may edit in any way, not necessarily one character at a time. User may type one character on a selected line, or paste whole line of text. Thus `toBeChanged` and `replacement` strings above may contain 0, 1 or more characters. Use `charAt()` to select a character.